# Appium stops sending commands

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium

I am automating one iOS app using appium. I have started appium using ProcessBuilder (java-client)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {appium,--no-reset});
pb.start();
```

I see that appium starts successfully. Then it executes some steps also. But intermittently it stops execution and nothing happens.

If I put above code in Runnable then everything works fine.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(newRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {appium,--no-reset});
            pb.start();
        });
thread.start();
```

I see some links which says that it could be because of race condition in logging part. Still I am not clear about the exact reason. We need to find out root cause of the issue.Does anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: Happened to me as well! Eventually solved it by executing using 'Apache Commons Exec' api.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are starting appium as a process in your code. so i think your execution waits till this process ends. That can be a issue. You can use separate .sh file to start the appium node.

use following parameters :- .node --no-reset --command-timeout 10000

use command time out parameter as well. it will help you.

Hopefully this will solve your issue.